# extract cited entries from bibliography with biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, biber

According to the manual and many posts I should be able to do:

```
    biber --output_format=bibtex test.bcf
```

And I'll get a new .bib file called test_biber.bib containing all cited
entries in test.tex, in citation order. But, when I do that, and then I get:

```
 Biber: Output format 'bibtex' is only valid in tool mode
```

So I added the --tool, but then biber expects a bib file and looks for test.bcf.bib. So it doesn't work. And if I use mybibfile.bib as an argument, then it just rewrites mybibfile_biber.bib with nicer format. So, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your first invocation works fine for me.  Which version of `biber` are you running.

Comment: I'm using biber version: 1.7

Comment: The current one is 1.8

Comment: well, it worked :) I may have used the future manual. If you answer, I'll just close the thread...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an older version of biber