# seeking bibtool for Windows binary

Tags: bibtex, windows

For a book, I need to be able to extract the cited references from a number of
.bib files to make a single .bib containing only those cited.

For this task,
I find bibtool extremely useful on linux, but am unable to use it on
Windows (XP, 32 bit), because it is only distributed as C source,
and I am unable to compile it, lacking the necessary compiler tools.
I've tried several times, but keep running into errors I can't resolve.

The author steadfastly refuses to make compiled binaries available, so I wonder if some kind soul would compile it for Windows and make the
binary available somewhere, perhaps on CTAN or some other web location.

Comment: Can you live with some other method? If so, I have a way out.

Comment: Following up on Harish's comment, you can do it with JabRef: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98370/how-to-generate-a-bib-file-with-citations-in-a-texmaker-project/98396#98396 Edit: Not sure if it can handle multiple files, so perhaps some manual labour is required.

Comment: [extract cited entries from bibliography with biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151498)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on your own!

Simply install Cygwin with its `gcc` and `make` packages. Then download the `bibtool` source  from CTAN and unpack it. Change to the directory and run (in Cygwin's `bash`):

```
./configure

make

make install
```

Do don't need the last step, if you put `bibtool.exe` somewhere in Windows `PATH`!

It's straightforward! ;-)

EDIT: This [link](http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/) explains how to install Cygwin with gcc & make to execute the above commands.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but as you mentioned, only in a `bash` shell (not MSDOS `cmd`) Actually, simply putting `bibtool.exe` on the Windows path is not sufficient.  One also needs the `lib/*.rsc` files, and to set an environment variable `BIBTOOLRSC`.