# Problem with bibtool when extracting bibliography information from an aux file in LaTeX/BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibtool

It seems that the latest version of [`bibtool`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/) (2.67) has a problem reading .aux files.

MWE (from [here](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/)):

1. a file named `exampl_01.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Random citation \cite{DUMMY:1} embedded in text.

\newpage

\bibliography{lesson7a1} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

2. a file named `lesson7a1.bib`:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}
```

Upon LaTeXing the above, we get (among others) the file `exampl_01.aux`, which has the content

```
\relax 
\citation{DUMMY:1}
\bibdata{lesson7a1}
\bibcite{DUMMY:1}{1}
\bibstyle{plain}
```

Then we run bibtool as follows

```
bibtool  -x exampl_01.aux -o used_references.bib
```

We get the output

```
*** BibTool WARNING: File bibstyle not found.
```

The file `used_references.bib` is produced, but is empty.

Note that the [manual](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/bibtool.pdf) (pp. 10-11, *1.2.4. Extracting Entries for a Document*) gives the following sample command: `bibtool -x document.aux -o document.bib`. Thus, it seems the above should have worked, but it doesn't.

If we simply erase the line `\bibstyle{plain}` from the .aux file and rerun bibtool, we get the error message

```
*** BibTool WARNING: File bibcite not found.
```

The file `used_references.bib` is again empty. 
Finally, if we also erase the `\bibcite{DUMMY:1}{1}` line from the the .aux file and rerun bibtool, we get no error messages and the file `used_references.bib` contains what we expect, namely,

```
@Book{        dummy:1,
  author    = "John Doe",
  title     = "The Book without Title",
  publisher = "Dummy Publisher",
  year      = "2100"
}
```

I see this behavior both under kubuntu 18.04 and under cygwin. In the bibtool documentation, I see no mention of this.

I used to be able to do this without any errors.

Is this a bug in the newest version of bibtool? (Which is actually not that new: executing `bibtool -help` gives 2017 as the most recent year.) Am I doing something wrong?

There is a hack that has worked for me so far: use `grep` to extract just the relevant lines from the .aux file (namely those that begin either with `\citation` or with `\bibdata`), and run `bibtool` on that file. Here's one way to do it:

```
grep -E '\\citation|\\bibdata' exampl_01.aux  > cleaned-up_aux_file.aux
bibtool  -x cleaned-up_aux_file.aux -o used_citations_01.bib 
rm cleaned-up_aux_file.aux
```

The problem is that I don't really know the details of how either BibTeX or `bibtool` work 'under the hood', and so I don't know if this hack really solves the problem in all circumstances, or if I have just been lucky so far.

Questions:

1. Is the described behavior a bug?
2. Is there a better workaround than the hack I described?
3. Are there any potential problems that my hack could create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in fact a bug in version 2.67. It has been fixed in 2.68. Since 2.68 has not been released officially yet, you can retrieve the latest version from the repository at https://github.com/ge-ne/bibtool/
I will make an official release in the near furture.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Gerd (author and maintainer of BibTool)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have downloaded and compiled version 2.68 (instructions here if anyone needs them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181005/192504 Formally that's for cygwin, but it will work on linux as well—it did for me). Bibtool version 2.68 indeed has the expected behavior.